# Are two svn commands the same ?

Tags: svn, merge, branch, trunk

I create a branch for myApp, for example myApp1.0 at revision 100, the next revision on trunk is 101. My svn code structure is:

```
/trunk/myApp
/branches/myApp1.0
```

After doing some work on `trunk/myApp`, I want to merge works on trunk to `branches/myApp1.0`, are the two svn commands the same?

1. `svn merge https://my.svn.server/branches/myApp1.0@100 https://my.svn.server/trunk/@HEAD`
2. `cd to work directory of myApp1.0`
   `svn merge -r101:HEAD  https://my.svn.server/trunk/myApp`

Comment: Note that you can also just cd to the branch work directory and use `svn merge ^/trunk` - you don't need to specify revision numbers in most situations (might require svn version 1.6+ ?).

Answer (score 0):

> are the two svn commands the same?

To *some degree*: both merges **merge** trunk and branch, they are different form of single merge command ('catch-up' merge mixed with '2-URL-merge' (1) vs 'cherry-pick' merge (2)) and 2-URL-merge recommended as "tool of last resort"

> svn help merge

...

> You should use this merge variant only if the other variants do not  apply to your situation, as this variant can be quite complex to  master.

BTW, in your use-case for catch-up merge you can (? TBT) eliminate PEG-revisions in URLS, for SVN >= 1.6 mergeinfo will be properly used

And note about used 2-URL-merge

> Two source URLs are specified, together with two revisions N and M.
>        The two sources are compared at the specified revisions, and the
>        difference is applied to TARGET_WCPATH, which is a path to a **working
>        copy of another branch**.